# IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 Community Edition not showing Spring Boot as an option for Run Configurations

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

As the title says, I have a project that has multiple spring boot projects in separate modules. However, after I have built the project, and try to make a run configuration Spring is not coming up as an option
[image: Spring missing]

[image: Project structure]

Here is the project structure for the module I am currently working on

I have disabled all my 3rd party spring plugins and rebuilt without luck

It is not showing as an available framework as well even though we have the dependency in our pom.xml

Im not sure what is going on so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot run configuration type is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition.

See [this table](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) comparing the features of the free and paid versions.

It shows that Spring Boot support is not available in the Community edition:

[image: boot]

Comment: Is there a 3rd party alternative out there? I know other developers that had the spring configuration while running with the community edition

Comment: Spring Boot apps can be started via Maven (`mvn spring-boot:run`) configuration or via Application configuration for the class that has `public static void main` method, see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html#run-from-editor).